# Array representation in XML

Tags: xml, pugixml

I have an XML node that I want to represent two integer values and an integer array. I have chosen to do it like this:

```
<MyNode a="4" b="8">
    <c_array>
        <c_value>"1"</c_value>
        <c_value>"2"</c_value>
        <c_value>"3"</c_value>
    </c_array>
</MyNode >
```

I wonder if I am being inconsistent by representing a and b as attributes and c as a node.  But it seems possible to read attributes as integers:

```
int a = myNode.attribute("a").as_int();
```

but nodes themselves only have the value() method, which returns char*. What is the reasoning for that?

Is my 'inconsistency' reasonable style?

I am failing to read the values of c (I'm using pugixml):

```
pugi::xml_node myNode = parentNode.child("MyNode");
pugi::xml_node c_array = parentNode.child("c_array");
for (pugi::xml_node c_value = c_array.child("c_value"); c_value; c_value = c_value.next_sibling("c_value"))
{
    printf("c value: %s\n", c_value.value());
}
```

With this code, no value is printed. Any idea why? Should the value of c_value be in quotes or not?

Comment: MyNode has no child named c_value, it only has a child c_array. That’s why there’s no output. Quotes depend on how you want the data. XML doesn’t need them in any way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have corrected the code (see above) but am still getting no value.

Comment: Solved it. Omitted the quotes and used c_value.text().as_int().